# Is current ankhsvn version compatible with current svn? version

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

Running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Windows 7 client.

I downloaded and installed VisualSVN Server 2.5.2 without a problem. The page [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) indicates that this is built against Subversion 1.7.2.

I downloaded and installed TortoiseSVN 1.7.3 without a problem. The page [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) indicates that this is built against Subversion 1.7.2.

Now I would like to install ankhsvn for use with Visual Studio 2010. The latest version is 2.3.10509 and the page [here](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ankhsvn/changelog) indicates that this is built against Subversion 1.7.1.

Does anyone know if this will run correctly against my SVN server? Or do I need to wait until ankhsvn release a version built agains SVN 1.7.2? If I need to wait, how promptly do ankhsvn releases usually appear?

Source control is obviously critical so I don't want to risk losing any data by "just trying it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion versioning requires clients to have the same minor version. So any 1.7.X client should be compitable with every other 1.7.Y client.

For the server, any 1.X client will work with any 1.Y client.

Of course it's a good idea to keep things as up-to-date as possible, but you're not risking anything by combining 1.7.1 and 1.7.2.

The release of AnkhSVN based on 1.7.2 will be out in the coming days, the daily builds are already using this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm aware of, we had to upgrade SVN on our servers to be compatible with the latest version of ankhsvn. It was a big deal, for the leads let us know we couldn't use ankh until we updated.

We are also using Tortoise.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it sounds like your problem was the other way round.